# How can I read a value from an array of dictionaries stored in GSettings with Vala?

Tags: linux, gtk, vala, gsettings, gvariant

The [GSettings Vala docs](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.Settings.get_child.html) are not very detailed and I can't find a way to read an item from an array of dictionaries stored in GSettings.
Right now I have this in my schema:

```
<key type="aa{ss}" name="services">
    <default>[{"id": "postgresql", "name": "PostgreSQL"}]</default>
    <summary></summary>
    <description></description>
</key>
```

How can I read the values for the keys `id` and `name` of the first value of the `services` array?
I tried a lot of possibilities (using `get_value("services")` then `get_child(0)`, for example) to read the dictionary but it simply breaks and I don't know how to debug it.

Comment: Please add an MCVE, otherwise we'd have to do a lot of work to reproduce.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff gonna do it and update it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Your format string `aa{ss}` is for an "array of array of dicts of string keys and string values" --- note the double array. You probably want just `a{ss}`, then you can access the dicts via `get_child(0)` as you were doing, then get lookup the values from the variant returned from that using `lookup_value(...)`

Comment: I tried that and got  `failed to parse <default> value of type 'a{ss}': 1-43:can not parse as value of type '{ss}'.  This entire file has been ignored.`, it seems that my format string is correct (I created it based on [this](https://people.gnome.org/~ryanl/glib-docs/gvariant-format-strings.html#gvariant-format-strings-dictionaries), where it seems to imply that in `a{sv}` is the whole dictionary because a dictionary is just an array of arrays).

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem was that somehow my settings instance wasn't being initialized correctly when created inside a `static construct` block. Moving the creation of that to a memoized method solved the problem.